# How to ask not to chew gum?

Tags: professionalism, communication, colleagues

How to tell your boss, with whom you have a very positive working relationship, that its kind of irritating that he‘s chewing gum during meetings and 1 on 1‘s?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Don't.**

Don't berate your boss for something as insignificant as chewing gum. Maybe you'll find a way that minimizes tension, but the risk is you'll get some kind of fallout. Endure it, and learn to ignore it. I know this doesn't answer your question but...

To put it this way, I can probably make a better answer if you indicate how much future career mobility and salary you are willing to sacrifice - in order to get your boss to stop chewing gum.

Answer (score 7):

I've been in this exact situation, as I'm very sensitive to certain noises, and chewing ranks high up on that list.

I simply said: "Hey, I'm sorry but I am very sensitive to certain noises, and chewing is one of them. I know most people aren't bothered, but for me it's like nails on a chalkboard. Do you think you could try not to chew gum when we're in meetings?"

Since you already have a positive working relationships, chances are that your boss, like mine, will be happy to oblige with such a reasonable request.

Comment: I think this is a very acceptable answer in meetings.  It sucks though when you have a noisy neighbor and all you can do is use headphones.

Comment: +1 - I chew gum frequently at work. If one of my reports, peers, or bosses is bothered by it, I would appreciate a comment like Jenny D proposed. I would NOT appreciate, "Chris, you chewing gum all the time is kind of irritating."

Comment: you can not say this to your **boss**.

Comment: @Fattie What's appropriate to say to your boss, as well as how to express it, is highly culture dependent - in terms of the country/area you're in, the culture within the company where you work, as well as the relationship with the manager in question. As I said, I have literally said this exact thing to my boss, with only positive results.